# How do I get news feed data from MS teams API?

Tags: api, rest, microsoft-teams

I am working on automation where I would like to news feed data filtered by some dedicated user. Can we achieve that?
If yes What could the REST API call look like?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share more details on your issue?

Comment: I am looking into a way to embed Teams Channel updates that appear as news in one of my web app. Is it feasible?

Comment: Please go through the following link to [track all changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatmessage?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#subscribe-to-changes-at-the-tenant-level) using subscriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to messages across all channels.

Please go through the following link to [track all changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatmessage?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#subscribe-to-changes-at-the-tenant-level) using subscriptions.